# Trying to write a generic enum util class in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, enums

## Problem

We have multiple enum types that have some `public static EnumType valueOfText(String text)`, for the purpose of mapping the contents of a data file cell to enum.

I'm trying to write a generic enum util that takes a comma-separated string and return multiple enum values. For example, we have the following enum:

```
public enum Frequency {
    SEMI_ANNUAL("S"), MONTHLY("M"), QUARTERLY("Q"), ANNUAL("A")

    public final String textValue;

    public Frequency(String textValue) {
        this.textValue = textValue;
    }

    public static Frequency valueOfText(String textValue) {
        for (Frequency frequency : values()) {
            if (frequency.textValue.equals(textValue))
                return frequency;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and string `"A,S"` which we want to convert to `[Frequency.ANNUAL, Frequency.SEMI_ANNUAL]`.

## Attempted solution

I create some `EnumUtils` like so:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors

public final class EnumUtils {
    public static final String LIST_SEPARATOR = ",";

    public static <E extends Enum<E>> List<E> CreateFromText(String text) {
        List<String> textList = text.split(this.LIST_SEPARATOR)

        return textList.stream()
                .map { txt ->
                    E.valueOfText(txt)
                }
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
    }
}
```

### What happen after said solution

We go to use it, like this:

`EnumUtils.CreateFromText<Frequency>(row[3])`

and the IDE compain, immediately, about the `<>`.

How can we specify enum type in this?

Comment: First feeling - why you are using groovy to write code in java...

Comment: @daggett because this is for a Katalon Studio project, and Katalon Studio code is written in Groovy.

What else would you like to ask, that has nothing to do with my actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy you can do it if you pass the actual `Class` instead of just using a type parameter.

```java
enum Frequency {
    SEMI_ANNUAL("S"), MONTHLY("M"), QUARTERLY("Q"), ANNUAL("A")

    final String textValue;

    Frequency(String textValue) {
        this.textValue = textValue;
    }

    static Frequency valueOfText(String textValue) {
        return values().find { it.textValue == textValue }
    }
}

final class EnumUtils {
    static <E extends Enum<E>> List<E> createFromText(Class<E> clazz, String text) {
        return text.split(",").collect { clazz.valueOfText(it) }
    }
}
```

```
EnumUtils.createFromText(Frequency, "S,M")
```

The same idea won't work in Java, since `clazz` won't have `valueOfText` at compile time.

Perhaps the Util class doesn't save you much typing, though:

```java
"S,M".split(",").collect(Frequency.&valueOfText)
```

Comment: It's not about trying to save typing. It's about building a robust system for my code.

Per the question description, this string being converted is coming from a data file.

Comment: The source of the data doesn't change my answer. Just replace `"S,M"` in my answer with `row[3]`.